# LDAP LDIF Java Parsing & New Lines

Tags: java, xml, parsing, ldap, ldif

I have some code that transforms an excel sheet into an LDIF statement. I was curious that when I create a new line is there a proper way to do it so that when I try to run the LDIF there won't be any errors? For now I just have \r\n at the end of every line. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: What's the actual problem here? Does \r\n work or not?

Comment: The only issue I was concerned about was if I attempt to run the LDIF which I am creating as a simple .txt file LDAP may not recognize the new lines. There may be no issue at all, just looking for an LDAP expert to clear it up.

Answer (score 1):

Use the [UnboundID LDAP SDK](https://www.unboundid.com/products/ldap-sdk/). There is an LDIF package enclosed.